# How to get data from already fetched rtk-query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to get already fetched data in Navbar from profileApi which used in profile component.
I want to display image on Navbar but image is available in profileApi and contains lots of user data, so i dont want to call same API for navbar just for image.

So is there any way to achieve this? or can we set data profileApi data to redux store somehow and get from there, like we do without rtk-query.

if somehow data set to redux store then how gonna access from rtk reducers?

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: AuthSlice.reducer,
    [UsersPostApi.reducerPath]: UsersPostApi.reducer,
    [ProfileApi.reducerPath]: ProfileApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat([
      UsersPostApi.middleware,
      ProfileApi.middleware,
    ]),
});
```

for **auth** i can do

```
let { data } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```

But How to access ProfileApi to get data in any component?

`Update:` the route /api/profile/:id
im using params to get user data in profile

```
let { userbyname } = useParams();
const { data, error } = useGetProfileQuery(userbyname);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it’s `not recommended` and suggested as `no go` pattern to have multiple api’s in same app. You have `injectEndpoints` and `enchanceEndpoints`, more [link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting)

As for the question answer, after you do:

```
const { data, isLoading 
, isError, error } = useProfileQuery(undefined)
```

You can do the same anywhere in your app, and get data from cache. You don’t need to do anything more then that.

Note the `undefined` passed as args, this is used as key for accessing cached data when query doesn’t have any `args`.

Comment: You don't *need* to pass the `undefined` explicitly.  It's fine if you do, but `useProfileQuery()` is the same thing.

Comment: @antokhio im using params inside `useGetProfileQuery(username)`
pls check i have updated question

Comment: @LindaPaiste yeah but thats not case here.

Comment: @folov55205 just call the same query with same param in the navbar, it will give you cached data

Comment: @antokhio result undefined cause, navabr is available for all components and no params in homepage except `profile/user1`.  so its not working

Comment: Well the way it works, it’s converting to string anything inside useQuery({…}), so to get the data you have make sure that part {…} is exactly same in both places.

Comment: I’m also not sure for the case you are after, might you wanna check extraReducer https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers